# Terminal hangs on open

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, rvm, freeze

I was attempting to get Rails installed; the installation failed and since then every time I've opened Terminal I get this:

```
Last login: Sun Nov 24 14:51:16 on ttys000
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
ERROR: Missing proper 'which' command. Make sure it is installed before using RVM!

[Process completed]
```

It is not responding to any keystrokes. What can I do?

Mac OS X 10.8.5

Comment: Try and rename open your `~/.profile` file and see if that helps. If so, it means the installation probably left some commands in there that are not working and leading Bash to exit.

Comment: Boot into single user mode, go to the home folder for your account, edit the `.profile` and remove the new commands that are bad. Instructions for entering single user mode are here: http://blog.microcentertech.com/2011/08/how-to-enter-single-user-mode-in-mac-os.html

Answer (score 0):

Using a tool like sublime text (free) open your home folder. (File ... Open... select your home folder.)

Locate the .bash_profile file and check any lines like "export PATH=..."
If there are multiple path's they all need to be separated by the : (colon)

Other files to check are .bashrc and .profile

Worst case, you can comment out the lines by putting the # symbol at the beginning of the line (hashtag/pound)
After saving (Cmd+S), open Terminal.

There are some great resources online for setting your .bash_profile / configuring your PATH to work with RVM (The ruby version manager).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

Using your file browser remove `$HOME/.rvm` - this kind of problems usually means that your computer shell is seriously misconfigured ... or that you have installed lots of conflicting software.

Comment: if you remove the $HOME/.rvm folder you will loose the Ruby Version Manager (RVM) ... This wouldn;t be the first step in troubleshooting.

Comment: Chances are that you have botched your .bash_profile or .profile file and the $PATH variable is wrong or missing a separator (:).
open an editor like atom or sublime text and look at your .bash_profile file in your home folder (with sublime text you can open a folder and all files (even hidden ones will be visible) if the path looks ok (there should be a : between each path) look at the .profile and then at the .bashrc files ... i bet one of them has a whole bunch of messed up. 
commenting out all lines (use the # as the first character per line) will get you back into Terminal.